# 'Easter egg' : est-il connu ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

> Un easter egg (terme anglais pour « œuf de Pâques ») est, en informatique ou dans les jeux vidéo1, une fonction cachée au sein d'un programme (image animée, jeu, message électronique, etc.) accessible grâce à un mot-clé ou à une combinaison de touches ou de clics : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg

La tournure 'easter egg' est-elle employée couramment ? Je crois que 'oeuf de Pâques' ne se dit pas dans ce contexte (et je crois que même la tradition chrétienne de décoration n'est pas connue).

Par exemple, peut-on rendre

> If you want to dig into the programming philosophy of experienced Python users, a nice little Easter egg exists in the Python interpreter; simply run import this.

par

> Si vous voulez vous plonger dans la philosophie de programmation des utilisateurs expérimentés de Python, un joli 'Easter Egg' existe dans l'interpréteur Python ; exécutez simplement import this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si *Easter Egg* se traduit bien par « Œuf de Pâques » et que certains dictionnaires ou sites le traduisent, ce n'est que pour information, mais en fait ils emploient *easter egg* dans leurs exemples<sup>1</sup>.
Je n'ai pas trouvé beaucoup de sites n'éprouvant pas le besoin de rappeler que c'est une traduction du terme anglais<sup>2</sup>.

> Je crois que 'oeuf de Pâques' ne se dit pas dans ce contexte (et je crois que même la tradition chrétienne de décoration n'est pas connue).

Même si la décoration de l'œuf de Pâques décoré existe depuis longtemps dans la chrétienté, il me semble que ce n'est pas tant la décoration de l’œuf à laquelle il est fait référence dans l'*easter egg* informatique que la **surprise** que certains œufs de Pâques en chocolat peuvent contenir, ou la notion de surprise que constitue la découverte des œufs cachés lors de la traditionnelle chasse aux œufs le jour de Pâques, chasse aux œufs beaucoup plus présente dans les pays anglo-saxons (dont les États-Unis d'où est originaire l'*easter egg*) qu'en France.
Et si on me demandait quel nom donner à ces *easter-eggs* non comestibles je serais tentée par « surprise ».

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> –[wordreference](https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/Easter%20egg) (Informatique) œuf de Pâques nm   *Il y a un easter egg dans le programme*.

– [Journal du net](https://www.journaldunet.fr/guides-d-achat/guide-du-jeu-video/1502951-easter-egg-definition-traduction-exemple/) Le terme anglais Easter Egg se traduit en français par Œuf de Pâques. [*La salle cachée contenant les plans d'Arkham City est l'un des nombreux Easter Egg du jeu Batman : Arkham Asylum*.](https://www.journaldunet.fr/guides-d-achat/guide-du-jeu-video/1502951-easter-egg-definition-traduction-exemple/)</sup>  
<sup><sup>2</sup> 2 pour l'instant, [ici](https://www.shop-justforgames.com/le-top-5-des-oeufs-du-jeu-video-c1200x55175) et [ici](https://fr.gameme.eu/oeufs-de-paques-de-guy-gratuits-toutes-les-principales-references-et-camees-de-jeux-video/).</sup>     
<sup><sup>3</sup> [Voir Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%92uf_de_P%C3%A2ques)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

La tradition de décorer et cacher des œufs pour Pâques est bien connue en France.

L'extension de ce sens à des propriétés cachées d'un programme ne l'est pas forcément, en particulier des moins jeunes et autres personnes peu adeptes de jeux vidéo, mais quand c'est le cas, c'est toujours le nom anglais qui est utilisé.